# Segmentation fault in linked list traversal in main method in C

Tags: c, linked-list

Getting segment zsh: segmentation fault (core dumped) when traversing a linked list from main method. But works fine when invoking the printList method.   Would like to get some intuitive explanation and how to make it work from main method.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
struct Node{
   int data;
   struct Node *next;
};

void printList(struct Node *head){
   struct Node *cursor= head;
   while(cursor !=NULL){
     struct Node currentNode = *cursor;
     printf("%d -->",currentNode.data);    
     cursor=currentNode.next;
   }
}

int main(){
   struct Node *head;     
   struct Node node1;
   node1.data=11;
   struct Node node2;
   node2.data=12;
   struct Node node3;
   node3.data=13;
   struct Node node4;
   node4.data=14;   

  // printf("Node 1 %d ",node1.data);
  // printf("Node 2 %d ",node2.data);
  // printf("Node 3 %d ",node3.data);

   head = &node1;
   node1.next=&node2;
   node2.next=&node3;
   node3.next=&node4;
  // printf("Node 1 %d ",node1.data);
  // printf("Node 2 %d ",node2.data);
  // printf("Node 3 %d ",node3.data);   
  // printList(head); 
struct Node *cursor= head;
   while(cursor !=NULL){
       struct Node currentNode = *cursor;
       printf("%d -->",currentNode.data);
       cursor=currentNode.next;
    }


   return 0;
}
```

Comment: Why are you copying your node structures when printing them?  Why not just use pointers?  Making local copies of the structures makes no sense.

Comment: Your bug is that `node4.next` is undefined, so when you reach the end of the list, you are picking up an undefined value.  If that value isn't `NULL`, you will try to dereference an undefined pointer.

Comment: @TomKarzes but same code when i comment the while loop and i invoke through the method printList. it's workign fine. I made local copies of structures  for debugging and log the address locations.

Comment: Try to understand.  `node4.next` will contain whatever value happens to be on the stack.  It could be anything.  It's undefined behavior.  If you write code like this, you should expect to get segmentation faults and you will not be able to predict them reliably.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Make `node4.next=NULL` to end the traversing. This is why you are facing problem.

Otherwise your check condition of `cursor!=NULL` would never terminate. Because it contains some garbage value. (if you don't initialize)

- Also for 100 nodes would you write this whole creation process 100 times?

You should create a method to add the node to the head of the list. That will be ideal.

Also read a bit about dynamic memory allocation. To give you a push I am providing some idea. Read it , check the manual.

For example, if you want to allocate a node dynamically. You can do something like this:-

```
struct node *tempNode;
tempNode = malloc(sizeof(struct node));
if(tempNode == NULL){
    fprintf(stderr,"%s","Error in malloc");
    exit(1);
}
..
...
```

Whatever you allocate using `malloc`, free it at the end of the logic.

something like,

```
free(tempNode);
tempNode=NULL;
```

---

To answer to your comment:- Don't rely on undefined behavior. Dereferencing a garbage value invokes Undefined behavior. You must avoid it to make your program behavior stable.

---

Small thing to note

```
 struct Node currentNode = *cursor;
 printf("%d -->",currentNode.data);
```

Can be done easily in single line

```
 printf("%d -->",cursor->data); //Also (*cursor).data
```

Comment: i was just testing it so adding nodes in this way. 
But why would it work when invoked through method  printList even when node4 next was not assigned to NULL?

Comment: @NavyCody.: check the answer..I modified

Comment: it would be highly helpful to address the main issue, why when invoked through method printList there's no segment error

  Right  After 
   node3.next=&node4;
   printList(head); //this is working fine

Comment: @NavyCody.: It is being explained...you can run this code several times...it is undefined behavior. it may blow up in my machine or even more in one run in your machine it works..in another run it may not. Both of the code is code capable of blwing up

Comment: does it has something to do with like "functional declaration printList would allocate seperate memory stack to its local variables and would not interfere with the main stack. ?

Comment: @NavyCody.: Nope

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/157797/discussion-between-navycody-and-coderredoc).

Comment: @NavyCody.: If you have any doubt...you can ask questions in comments.